# React: show message if no image in Api using ternary operator. Getting parsing error: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, api, conditional-operator

I am working on a project in ReactJS. Basically it is accessing data from an Api.  Below is the code from the App.js

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
this.state ={
  signs:  []
 }
}

componentDidMount(){
var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
targetUrl = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/openplaques/open-plaques-london-2019-03-13.json'
fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(plaque => this.setState({signs: plaque}));
  }
render(){
return(
  <div className='App'>
    <CardList signs={this.state.signs}/>
  
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

I have another component that is a showing the card list.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from '../card/card.component';
import './card-list.styles.css';

export const CardList = (props)=> {
console.log(props);
return <div className='card-list'>
   {props.signs.map(sign => (
       <Card key={sign.id} sign={sign} />
   ))}
  </div>
  }
```

The card component of the app has the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './card.styles.css';
export const Card = (props) => (
<div className='card-container'>
   
   {(props.sign.photographed?) ? <img alt="sign" src={props.sign.thumbnail_url} width="200" 
   height="200"/> : null}
    <h1>{props.sign.title}</h1>
    <p>{props.sign.inscription}</p>
    </div>
    )
```

This is where I am having the problem as I am getting the error above.  Not all the entries in photographed? have an entry.  So I am trying using a ternary operator if there is no image in the Api.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra `?` here: `(props.sign.photographed?)`

Comment: That is the property name in API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

If you have a property named `.photographed?`, then try accessing it by calling `props.sign["photographed?"]`.

---

See this line:

> `{(props.sign.photographed?) ? <img alt="sign" src={props.sign.thumbnail_url} width="200"`

More specifically, see:

> `{(props.sign.photographed?) ?`

A bit more...

> `...photographed?)`

*(if it's not obvious, see the extra `?`).*

A ternary syntax is `condition ? truthy : falsey`. Therefore, your line should be:

```
{props.sign.photographed ? <img alt="sign" src={props.sign.thumbnail_url} width="200"
...
```

Comment: Cool will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Your field name as a special character in it `?`. You need to use bracket syntax to access it properly:

```
// Invalid
props.sign.photographed?
// Valid
props.sign["photographed?"]
```